# hasManyThroughrelationship return wrong SQL sentence

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, orm

I would like to get some data for tables that dont have a directly relation. The context is the following:

```
//** account_table **// Normal user, who can buy any book
account_id
account_info

//** book_table **// Books
book_id
account_id
author_id

//** author_table **// Author, who can write a lot of books (they will have more functions, this is the why i choose to create other table)

author_id
book_id
author_desc
```

The models that im using are:

```
class Account extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    protected $table = 'account_table';
    protected $primaryKey = 'account_id';

    public function Book()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Book', 'account_id');
    }

    public function Author()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Author', 'Book','account_id','book_id');
    }
}

class Book extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    protected $table = 'book_table';
    protected $primaryKey = 'book_id';

    public function Account()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Account','account_id');
    }

    public function Author()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Author', 'author_id', 'author_id');
    }  
}

class Author extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    protected $table = 'author_table';
    protected $primaryKey = 'author_id';

    public function Book()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Book', 'author_id');
    }
}
```

So to get this information i use the following code:

```
$user = Account::find(166); //user
dd($user->Author);
```

The ouput throw an error like this:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'book.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `author_table`.*, `book_table`.`account_id` from `author_table` inner join `book_table` on `book_table`.`id` = `author_table`.`book_id` where `book_table`.`account_id` = 166)
```

Seems that it is looking for a field (id) that does not exist in my database, however i have defined all primaryKeys in the models. What should i do to get `author_desc` information in this context ?

**EDIT (other example):**

When i use the following code it retrieve the same error:

```
$user = Account::find(166);
echo Book::find(3);
```

Comment: I'd say there is something else at play here... I just setup a new project exactly as you described and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I have resume the problem because of the app is quite big now :/. Should i define a FK in the database table ? (not only in laravel)
@user1960364

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a one-to-one relationship of Book to Author with the `hasOne()` method and a many-to-many relationship between Author and Book with the `belongsToMany()` method. These should be inverse relationships, instead. Try replacing the `belongsToMany()`method with the `belongsTo()` method. Something like this:

```
class Account extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    protected $table = 'account_table';
    protected $primaryKey = 'account_id';

    public function Book()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Book', 'account_id');
    }

    public function Author()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Author', 'Book','account_id','book_id');
    }
}

class Book extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    protected $table = 'book_table';
    protected $primaryKey = 'book_id';

    public function Account()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Account','account_id');
    }

    public function Author()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Author', 'author_id', 'author_id');
    }  
}

class Author extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    protected $table = 'author_table';
    protected $primaryKey = 'author_id';

    public function Book()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Book', 'author_id');
    }
}
```